# How do I use relative path for a secret mountPath in deployment configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I'm having hard time configuring mountPath as a relative path.
Let's say I'm running the deployment from `/user/app` folder and I want to create secret file under `/user/app/secret/secret-volume` as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
          # name must match the volume name below
          - name: secret-volume
            mountPath: secret/secret-volume
  # The secret data is exposed to Containers in the Pod through a Volume.
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: test-secret
```

For some reason the file `secret-volume` is created in the root directory `/secret/secret-volume`.

Comment: How does Kubernetes know about the `/user/app` directory?  Is it mentioned elsewhere in a larger pod spec?

Comment: The container Mount path needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `mountPath: secret/secret-volume` change it to `mountPath: /user/app/secret/secret-volume`

[Check documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).